# How do i add this code so things appear in databse on website

Tags: javascript

just need to know where to put this code so that the jobs we put into our database called workable...show up on our website.

```
<script src='https://www.workable.com/assets/embed.js' 
    type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
    whr(document).ready(function(){
    whr_embed(226744, {detail: 'titles', base: 'jobs', zoom: 'country', 
      grouping: 'none'});
     });
 </script> 
 <div id="whr_embed_hook"></div>
```

I found the code I'm supposed to add: .whr-date {display: none;}

Answer (score 0):

You can include this code directly in the html of your website's careers page. For a WordPress site you will need to use a plugin, like [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/raw-html/) or [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/css-javascript-toolbox/) one.